# What is the difference between the following options (@Service, @Bean or Static method)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a general coding question for Spring boot.
Imagine you have a controller, when the user goes to a certain page, we read some data from a db, we do some business logic with this data and depending on the business logic we go to a different page. There a 3 ways that I can program this. The question is, which is the best method and why. This way, I'm trying to understand the different options. There are probably other options, so if you have a better suggestion, please let me know.
Another question, do you always create beans/components in Spring or do you sometimes program the class Java way?

Option 1: Static method
I read the data from the db in the controller class, in a different class I do some business logic in a static method and I return the new string.
This looks like this:

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private final RouteRepository routeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TestController (RouteRepository routeRepository) {
        this.routeRepository = routeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTestController() {
        List<Route> route= routeRepository.findAll();
        String total= Test.testMethod(route);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Business logic class:

```
public class Test {

    public static String testMethod(List<Route> route) {
        // do some business logic
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Option 2:
I read the data in a @Service class, in the same class I do the business logic. In my controller class I autowire the service class and I call a method in the @Service class:

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private final Test test;

    @Autowired
    public TestController (Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTestController() {
        String total= test.testMethod();
        return total;
    }
}
```

Business logic class:

```
@Service
public class Test {

    private final RouteRepository routeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public Test (RouteRepository routeRepository) {
        this.routeRepository = routeRepository;
    }

    public String testMethod() {
        List<Route> route= routeRepository.findAll();
        // do some business logic
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Option3:
Or I do the same as option1 but with a @Bean

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigAll.class);
    Test test = context.getBean(Test.class);

    private final RouteRepository routeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TestController (RouteRepository routeRepository) {
        this.routeRepository = routeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTestController() {
        List<Route> routes = routeRepository.findAll();
        String total= test.testMethod(routes);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Business logic:

```
@Service
public class Test {
    public String testMethod(List<Route> routes) {
        // do some business logic
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigAll {

    @Bean
    public Test getAddress() {
        return new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Option 2, however you wouldn't return "index", you'd rather return the actual `Routes` themselves.

Under the hood, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository` are all beans, one reason why they're different is to allow Spring Boot to implement the idea of "[testing slices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)". This allows you to test particular parts of your application in isolation.

For example, if you have a `RouteService`, you can completely mock this service out to return a `Route` without connecting to your database, and pass it directly to your presentation layer, e.g. a Thymeleaf template with and test it with a `@WebMvcTest`. Your presentation/HTTP layer should be as simple as possible, and not contain logic. Logic belongs in a `@Service`.

By using a `@Service` you can also benefit from annotations like `@Transactional`, which allows to to automatically rollback a unit of work, if there is an issue. In your Option 1, you only read all of your routes from a repository, however imagine if you also needed to update something, and your static method threw an exception: the system wouldn't rollback the update, as it would have already been committed.

As a rule of thumb, don't use static methods unless they are part of a library function e.g. a base64 encoder, which can be tested in complete isolation. The use of static methods make your system difficult to test, as you can't easily mock them out.

There is no benefit to using Option 3, as component scanning and annotations should make manual configuration unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following micro service like design as your service classes should be handling the business logic:

TestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path= "test-api")
public call TestController.java
    private final TestService testService;

    public TestController(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces= "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTestController() {
            List<Route> routeList = testService.findAllRoutes();

            return ResponseEntity.ok(routeList);
    }
}
```

TestService.java

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    private final TestDAO testRespository;

    public TestService(TestRespository testRepository) {
        this.testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    public List<Route> findAllRoutes() {
        return testRepository.findAllRoutes();
    }
}
```

TestDAO.java

```
public interface TestDAO {
    List<Route> findAllRoutes();
}
```

TestDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO {
    private static final String FIND_QUERY = <insert query here>;

    @Override
    public List<Route> findAllRoutes() {
        // Use query and return the list
    }
}
```

Notice that you'll be initializing the dependencies of the controller class and the service class in their constructors. This is due to the fact that it will make things easier for you to Mock these objects when it comes time to test using Mockito, etc. Now, when it comes to following question:

> Imagine you have a controller, when the user goes to a certain page,
>   we read some data from a db, we do some business logic with this data
>   and depending on the business logic we go to a different page

Since you're returning a list of "routes" from the db, technically you could handle the list of routes and only return a single route within the ResponseEntity for the client to consume and redirect on it's end.

The alternative would be to return the list of routes to the client, and let the business logic of the client handle it's own redirections based on the routes you have provided to it.